# TypeError (can't convert nil into Integer) paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I am using paperclip while creating new object for saving in database i am facing 
`can't convert nil into Integer paperclip` error

This is what i have written in my function.

```
def create
  @asset = Asset.new(params[:snap]) #here i am facing the above error.
  @asset.user_id = current_user.id
  @asset.save
  redirect_to "/"
end
```

This is what i am getting while posting form

```
{:original=>#<File:/tmp/stream20110929-1212-17asdf-0,6708,0>,  .... }
```

Any suggestions for solving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this error by applying the following patch.

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/commit/1bcfc14388d0651c5fc70ab9ca3511144c698903